# how to make shape of 3D mesh more accurate?

Tags: 3d, shapes, meshlab

my mesh doesn't provide a clear shape of bones on my scene (there are no boundaries when I don't use texture). Is there a way to make it more relevant, so that the depth or the shape of bones became more accurate? I tried to reconstruct the mesh using the filter "Screened Poisson Surface Reconstruction" but I didn't have an improvement. I put at your disposal some images to clarify more. the first one is for the mesh without texture or color information, and the second one is with color and texture. I'm working with Meshlab software to manipulate 3D objects.[mesh without color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oj0CL.png) [mesh with color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mI789.png)

Answer (score 0):

Add lighting. Without lighting and colors every mesh will be just a mess.

On your examples color gives a lot of difference, the same should apply with lighting.

Comment: Actually it is not what I am seeking for, and in fact this the problem I have because I am working on a 3D descriptor that explores just positions and normals, and I really can't have a good descriptor for the scene since objects on it are not relevant. . I was trying to reconstruct my mesh from images I have, by a software named Photoscan Agisoft, changing parameters but the problem is that even from images I have in disposal don't provide together a good information about the depth of objects.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Fill` mode rendering instead of `Wireframe`.